# dapper and running stored procedure ctx_ddl.sync_index

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dapper

I need to execute the stored procedure `ctx_ddl.sync_index` on an Oracle database.  In a query program this works;

```
EXECUTE ctx_ddl.sync_index('MyIndex');
```

When I try to run in dapper with the following;

```
using var connect = new OracleConnection(conString);
var results = connect.Execute("ctx_ddl.sync_index", "MyIndex", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

It gives me the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
> arguments in call to 'SYNC_INDEX'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing "MyIndex" as a string, try this:

```
using var connect = new OracleConnection(conString);

var p = new OracleDynamicParameters();
p.Add("THENAMEOFYOURPARAMETER", dbType: OracleDbType.THETYPEOFYOURPARAMETER, direction: ParameterDirection.Input);

var results = connect.Execute("ctx_ddl.sync_index", param:p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

Comment: Stupid question:  What namespace/NuGet is OracleDynamicParameters in?

Comment: Not stupid.. Should just be in `Dapper`, but I don't have VS here to verify.

Comment: So its not in the Dapper, but I did find it in Dapper.Oracle.DynamicParameter.  The issue is it hasn't been updated since 2018. I am running .NET Core and that is giving a version issue with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core